# .NET Framework - Possible memory-leaky classes?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks

Just the other day I was investigating a memory leak that was ballooning the app from ~50MB to ~130MB in under two minutes. Turns out that the problem was with the [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) class. Internally, the class stores a linked list of arrays. When an item is dequeued from the ConcurrentQueue, the index in the array is bumped, but the item remains in the array (i.e. it's not set to null). The entire array node is dropped after enough enqueues/dequeues, so it's not technically a *leak*, but if putting large objects in the ConcurrentQueue, this can get out of hand fast. The documentation makes no note of this danger.

I was wondering what other potential memory pitfalls are in the Base Class Library? I know about the Substring one (that is, if you call substring and just hold onto the result, the whole string will still be in memory). Any others you've encountered?

Answer (score 11):

You are correct. The bug is located in the method `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>+Segment.TryRemove(out T, ref ConcurrentQueue<T>.Segment)`.

If you look at this method in Reflector, you'll see the following line:

```
result = this.m_array[low];
```

There should be the following line after it:

```
this.m_array[low] = default(T);
```

For reference, you can see how this is correctly implemented in the method `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>.Dequeue()`.

Comment: Yup;  saw this in Reflector, too -- though I'm not sure if t would somehow break atomicity/threading?

Comment: No, it's definitely a bug. The bucket is protected in that region, and the code is designed to ensure that the value it contains is only ever read once.

Comment: BTW, I originally sent a report on this to someone at MS on Apr. 1. I just don't think they've had a chance to fix it yet. Unfortunately, the class is completely unusable until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Reported to Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552868/memory-leak-in-concurrentqueue-t-class-dequeued-enteries-are-still-rooted

Comment: @280Z28 -- Ah, I will search for the issue & vote on it. I'm surprised this issue made it into production, esp. since it was present in the System.Threading preview that was part of the Rx framework as well as .NET 4.

Comment: @Robert Fraser: I didn't file it at connect.microsoft.com because by the time I found it all I could do was drop a quick line to my superior and CC a contact at MS while I rewrote the code to use `Queue<T>` instead.

Comment: @280Z28 - Thanks for the vote of confidence. it looks like it was fixed, but they probably won't push it out until the next service pack.

Comment: Stephen Toub posted the following saying the behaviour is by design to support enumeration: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/05/08/concurrentqueue-lt-t-gt-holding-on-to-a-few-dequeued-elements.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Though not a direct memory leak or specific to .net/BCL, there is the string concatenation (using the += operator) issue. That's pretty CPU intensive in loops due to heavy garbage collecting.

Comment: Yup. Java solved this by converting it to use a StringBuilder; I don't know why .NET hasn't done the same.

Comment: .NET does have the same it's just under System.Text

Comment: The VS C# compiler is also smart enough to convert expressions like ("This " + "is" + " string #" + stringNumber) into StringBuilder internally, if it makes sense to do so.

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Fortunately you are not correct. For the case you mention, the compiler would actually emit a call to `string.Concat("This is string#", stringNumber)`. Literals are combined where possible, and the call is to `string.Concat` because it is faster than `StringBuilder` for a fixed number of append operations.

Answer (score -1):

The ConcurrentQueue will hold only a maximum of 31 dequeued objects. This shouldn't present a huge problem unless you're dealing with really large object graphs.

Anyway, it doesn't make sense using a ConcurrentQueue if you don't have enought space to allocate 32 objects...

Comment: What if I've got message queue? What if it's for the client connection of the server socket, so that there is 500 such queues? And every client decides to send me 32 messages each 10 KB long. I end up with 160 MB of Garbage. And if I've got 2000 such clients, or messages become bigger, I end up getting OutOfMemoryException and a program crash.

And hey, if I try to reuse this shitty queues, and pre-allocate loads of them, then I've got this garbage remembered even after the socket connection is closed. Clearly, it does make sense to use this queue, when it doesn't leak.